# How to replace a moving <img> with another one during movement using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a moving image that moves across the screen from left to right. I need to replace it in the middle of the screen with another image for 5 seconds and then replace it back again resume the movement. could anyone please help me with that ?

Here's the code I have so far. I'm new to this , any help would be very much appreciated ! Thanks in advance !

```js
const catImg = document.querySelector('img');
let marginLeft = (catImg.style.left = 0);
let marginRight = catImg.style.right;
const body = document.querySelector('body');

body.style.position = 'relative';

function catWalk() {
  let halfWidth = window.innerWidth / 2 - catImg.width / 2;
  marginLeft = '0px';
  if (
    parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(catImg).left) <
    Math.floor(window.innerWidth / 2 - catImg.width / 2)
  ) {
    marginLeft = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(catImg).left) + 10 + 'px';

    catImg.style.left = marginLeft;
    return;
  } else if (parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(catImg).left) == Math.round(halfWidth / 10) * 10) {
    catImg.src = 'https://tenor.com/StFI.gif';
    function dancingCat(timePassed) {
      let startTime, endTime;
      function start() {
        startTime = performance.now();
        return startTime;
      }
      function end() {
        endTime = performance.now();
        timePassed = endTime - startTime;
        console.log(timePassed);
        return endTime;
      }

      if (timePassed == 5000) {
        catImg.src = 'http://www.anniemation.com/clip_art/images/cat-walk.gif';
      }
    }
  } else if (
    parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(catImg).left) >
    window.innerWidth - catImg.width / 2
  ) {
    console.log('stop here');
    catImg.style.left = '0px';
    return;
  }
  return;
}

setInterval(catWalk, 50);

catWalk();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Cat Walk</title>
</head>

<body>
  <img style="position: absolute;" src="http://www.anniemation.com/clip_art/images/cat-walk.gif" />

  <script src="ex5-catWalk.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: do you want to change the gif in middle of the of the screen

Comment: one of the problems is that the link `https://tenor.com/StFI.gif` doesn't give you a "raw" gif image that can be displayed with `<img>`, but it give you a "full web page". try replacing it with `https://media1.tenor.com/images/2de63e950fb254920054f9bd081e8157/tenor.gif`

Comment: I'm not sure if `let marginLeft = (catImg.style.left = 0);` makes what you desire: First it set catImg.style.left to 0 and second it set marginLeft  to 0.

Comment: Yes @Arun, that's the Idea.

Comment: @MarcoLucidi Thank you ! I was aware that there is an issue with the link , but was saving looking into that for later after I solve the bigger issues. thanks for explaining what the problem is !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code I made a refactor separating each sentence between functions. BTW, try to avoid declare functions within functions. I'm giving you just an example of how can you make it. I'm sure it could be better turning each function as pure, but it works fine.

**Edition**

Adding some lines to `start` function you can achieve a loop cycle when the cat overflows the right side window.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Cat Walk</title>
</head>

<body>
  <img width="200" src="http://www.anniemation.com/clip_art/images/cat-walk.gif" />

  <script type="text/javascript">

    let interval, leftPos = 0, stopped = 0;

    const img = document.querySelector('img');
    const windowHalf = window.innerWidth / 2;
    const middlePos = windowHalf - img.width / 2;

    function step(img, size) {
      leftPos += size;
      return img.style.marginLeft = leftPos + 'px';
    }

    function start() {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (leftPos < window.innerWidth) {
          if (leftPos < middlePos || stopped) {
            return step(img, 5);
          } else {
            clearInterval(interval);
            return stop();
          }
        } else {
          // restart variables when cat overflows window area
          leftPos = 0;
          stopped = 0;
        }
      }, 50)
    }

    function stop() {
      img.src = 'https://tenor.com/StFI.gif';
      stopped++
      setTimeout(() => {
        img.src = 'http://www.anniemation.com/clip_art/images/cat-walk.gif';
        start()
      }, 5000)
    }

    start();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Marcelo ! 
I hope I could learn to write such clean and beautiful code soon. :D
I've been trying to modify on your code to make the cat repeat its journey infinitely. so far no luck... I tried to make a new function to restart from the initial position if the marginleft is greater than window.innerWidth. that's not working. Do you have any suggestions ? 
Thank you!

Comment: @Obi I've just edited my answer. I added a few lines to `start()` function to achieve what you asking for. Take a look.